# How to have a number related to each one of many to many field objects? (e.g. A score for a homework a student has done)

Tags: django, django-models

I'm making an Learning Management System. There's this model called Homework and User model which is basically a model for students.

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    # some code

class Homework(models.Model):
    # some code ...
    students_done = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='homeworks_done')
```

I wanted to keep track of students that have done a specific homework and I did it by adding `students_done` field. Now I want the teacher to have the option to give each student a score for a done homework. How can I save the score in the database? I just can't figure out what field to use and how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a through model:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    # some code

class Homework(models.Model):
    # some code ...
    students_done = models.ManyToManyField(..., through="UserHomework")

class UserHomework(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, ...)
   homework = models.ForeignKey(Homework, ...)
   number = models.IntegerField(...)
   ...
```